How to query whether a container is higher than the viewport?
I am playing around with container queries and trying to understand them better.
One idea I wanted to implement is to apply specific styles, when a container extends the viewport, or in other words when the content extends the container.
Based on an article, I tried it with container-type: size and adding height and overflow on the container element.
I made a CodePen with an example: https://codepen.io/Kageetai/pen/LYvMMwx
In there I wanted to make the text red, if the container is higher than the viewport.
My understanding from some other research though is that it's not possible to query for container height, at least not if it's a variable height, like height: 100% or so. It seems that might never be possible to implemented, due to the loop of rendering a specific height and then querying for the same height.
So my question is: Does anyone else have any insight on this and/or the current state of affairs around container queries?
Below the snippet where I am trying to explore this. I want the text to turn red, when .container is higher than the viewport (when it's scrollable).


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  container-type: size;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@container (height > 100%) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quasi a eveniet! Magni dicta autem cumque quisquam? Nesciunt, tempore, architecto ad quisquam, omnis iusto veritatis quidem autem sint officia eius!</p>
</div>




I'm not clear what 'container extends the viewport' means. The viewport is the viewport. For your code, testing height > 100vh works - so could you describe more exactly what you want to do. Also please put your code into the question (use <> in editor).

With "container" I was referring to the element that is defined as a container for the container query, here .container.  I added that info to the question text together with the code snippet. I was just using codepen at first, as I am more used to it.

Yes, I understand what container referred to, what I don't understand is 'container extends the viewport' - is there some confusion as to what the viewport is? It doesn't get extended by content.

I am sorry, I might have not used the word "extend" fully correctly, but I meant "extend past the size of the viewport", not like "expands the viewport"

To my understanding, this isn't possible.
When you define something as a size container (container-type: size), it automatically applies size containment to the element (contain: size), which means the element ignores its children when sizing. MDN.
